# Race condition makes integration test inconsistent

Tags: c#, winforms, race-condition, white-framework

I wrote a simple UI automation test for my application using [Project White](http://teststack.github.io/White/). It just launches the app and checks if the main window exists. This is done in the context of an NUnit test:

```
///AppTest.cs
[Test]
public void ShouldDisplayMainForm() {
   using( var wrapper = new WhiteWrapper( MYAPP_PATH ) ){
       Window win = wrapper.GetWindow( "MYAPP_MAIN_FORM_TITLE" );
       Assert.IsNotNull(win);
   }
}

///WhiteWrapper.cs
using System;
using White.Core;
using White.Core.Factory;
using White.Core.UIItems;
using White.Core.UIItems.WindowItems;

namespace MGClient.Test {

    internal class WhiteWrapper : IDisposable {
        private readonly Application mHost;
        private readonly Window mMainWindow;

        public WhiteWrapper( string pPath ) {
            mHost = Application.Launch( pPath );
        }

        public WhiteWrapper( string pPath, string pMainWindowTitle )
            : this( pPath ) {
            mMainWindow = GetWindow( pMainWindowTitle );
        }

        public void Dispose() {
            if( mHost != null )
                mHost.Kill();
        }

        public Window GetWindow( string pTitle ) {
            return mHost.GetWindow( pTitle, InitializeOption.NoCache );
        }

        public TControl GetControl<TControl>( string pControlName ) where TControl : UIItem {
            return mMainWindow.Get<TControl>( pControlName );
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the test results are random: sometimes it fails, sometimes it succeeds, without following a pattern.

The test environment is set so that initialization fails: I want to see the test fail consistently. The problem is that my app's main form performs its initialization and all related validations in the handler for its `Load` event. I think there is a race condition, due to the fact that White runs the application under test in a separate process:

When `GetWindow` is called before the initialization failure is detected, the test succeeds. When failure detection wins the race, it closes the app, so this makes `GetWindow` fail.

I'm looking through White documentation and browsing through samples, but I can't find a workaround for this scenario. Changing the app's code should be a last resort since I don't have a test harness yet (and that's what got me stuck: all my ideas revolve around changing the app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at `White.Core.UIItems.WindowItems.Window`'s public interface and found the `WaitTill` method, which paired with the `IsCurrentlyActive` property did the trick:

```
///AppTest.cs
[Test]
public void ShouldDisplayMainForm() {
   using( var wrapper = new WhiteWrapper( MYAPP_PATH ) ){
       Window win = wrapper.GetWindow( "MYAPP_MAIN_FORM_TITLE" );
       Assert.IsNotNull(win);
       win.WaitTill( ()=> win.IsCurrentlyActive );
   }
}
```

Now the test always fails. Sometimes it times out in the `GetWindow` call, sometimes it does in `WaitTill`. But it always fails when initialization does, so that's good enough for me.

To other White noobs: documentation is pretty scarce, so bear with it and look at the source (if you find some good doc source, please do tell).

Answer (score 1):

Create a [`WaitHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.aspx).
Add an event to `Loaded` which will reset the `WaitHandle` object.
In your test use `WaitHandle.WaitOne()`, which will cause it to sleep until `Load` is finished.

```
[Test]
public void ShouldDisplayMainForm() {
   using( var wrapper = new WhiteWrapper( MYAPP_PATH ) ){
       WaitHandle handle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
       Window win = wrapper.GetWindow( "MYAPP_MAIN_FORM_TITLE" );
       win.Loaded += (sender, e) => handle.set(); //Loaded or Onload, depending on framework
       handle.WaitOne();
       Assert.IsNotNull(win);
   }
}
```

There is a minor issue with this, if `Loaded` has already been called you will be waiting indefinitely.

---

You can check `IsHandleCreated` which will tell you if loading is complete.
Here's a crappy solution that will work.

```
[Test]
public void ShouldDisplayMainForm() {
   using( var wrapper = new WhiteWrapper( MYAPP_PATH ) ){
       Window win = wrapper.GetWindow( "MYAPP_MAIN_FORM_TITLE" );
       While (win.IsHandleCreated)
         Thread.Sleep(1000);
       Assert.IsNotNull(win);
   }
}
```

Comment: In a White test, I can only talk to my app through its GUI elements, since it runs in a separate process. I can't access its members or methods, so there would be no direct way for me to access the WaitHandle. Maybe I misunderstood you?

Comment: I went straight to your second solution since the first one does have a potential deadlock. It doesn't build, because win's type is `White.Core.UIItems.WindowItems.Window`, and `IsHandleCreated` is a method from the `Control` class. I'm now investigating how to access the underlying `Control` using `win`.